# The type '...' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Except type is not exposed (except that it is `public` by requirement)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dependencies, signalr

I see many posts about what `The type '...' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.` means but those posts don't cover this problem as far as I recognize.

I have a Library **AAA** that has signalR as a dependency.  The dependency should be of almost no consequence but one of it's details in reflection might matter somehow.

I have two other Executable projects in the same solution called **BBB** and **CCC**, both with seemingly identical project references to **AAA** and use **AAA** identically to self-host signalR with all the signalR usage fully encapsulated.

For months until yesterday, both **BBB** and **CCC** compiled just fine.  Now, with no meaningful changes I can find to the .cs files, the .csproj files, or otherwise, I get `The type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.` when compiling **BBB** but NOT when compiling **CCC**.

signalR requires that any `Hub` implementations are marked `public`.  So in **AAA**, `MyHub : Hub` implementation *is* `public`.  Otherwise it could be private.  There are no references to it in the other libraries, no members of **AAA** types which return a `Hub` or a `MyHub`.  If I mark `MyHub` private, both project compile fine.  (but it fails at runtime because of signalR's reflection logic expectations)

What's extra unhelpful is that the compiler error squiggles on just the "first" file in the **BBB** (project which happens to be mostly empty, one of the most bare-bones files) on the `BBB` of the `namespace BBB {` block.

Maybe this is a distraction, but I'm also confused how it decides on this file because even if I change the file name or the class name inside (to "zzz_ClassName" for example), it still picks that "same" file as the one to show the error in every time, unless I remove the file all together from the compilation (which conveniently happens to be mostly dead code at the moment anyway).  If I remove that file, the error moves to some other file consistently instead, also on the namespace line.  The short of it is that the ordering used to chose this "first" file doesn't seem to be alphabetical by filename, class name, nor by order in the .csproj file.

IF I NEEDED/USED/EXPOSED a MyHub object in **BBB** or **CCC**, **I would expect to get this exception**, but I don't expose it or use it.  Again, if I merely change `MyHub` to be `private` instead of `public`, all compile fine (but won't run).  Either way, **CCC** is compiling just fine, and I can't identify any meaningful difference in the code or the .csproj including the project references to **AAA**.  This just started happening, perhaps due to a code change (though I can't find it) or a cleaning out of old conflicting assemblies.

I have cleaned and rebuilt.  I've even manually deleted *.dll from explorer.  I've checked the GAC for old versions of an assembly (a possibility).  I have removed and readded the project references.  I have closed and reopened VS (2012).

Have you hit this before?  What do I need to look for?  What besides an exposed Hub or Hub-derived type or typed member could require a direct reference?  If, when merely the MyHub is marked private it compiles fine, what could BBB possibly be upset about?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using NuGet to uninstall (don't forget the "-RemoveDependencies" flag) then reinstall SignalR into your two projects?

Comment: The point is to NOT have signalR as an immediate dependency of BBB or CCC.  And please note that both AAA and CCC compile just fine.  And that until recently so was BBB, but I can't see any relevant changes that would make it stop, or any reason for it not to be working now anyway.

Comment: if you call the `MapSignalR()` method then you are exposing the hub, now did you install SignalR nuget package on both BBB and CCC?

Comment: `MapSignalR()` is called all within AAA and no signalR types leak into BBB or CCC.  No, the nuget package nor individual library references are part of either BBB or CCC.

Comment: (Well, this is self-host, so `WebApp.Start<SignalRHostStartupJSONP>(startOptions)` and `app.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);` are wrapped in AAA, whichever of those is the equivelent of `MapSignalR()` for self-host.)

Comment: It can also be something with project settings of BBB. For example `Target framework` or `Platform`.